# What to do with intentional duplicate questions on separate SE sites

Tags: support, exact-duplicates

The following questions:

https://superuser.com/questions/651439/frequent-wifi-disconnects-with-my-wifi-router

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54090/frequent-wifi-disconnects-with-my-wifi-router

are identical.  Asked by the same user at the same time.

Flagging a question as a duplicate requires that both questions be on the same StackExchange board.  Should there be a mechanism to flag cross-board duplicates or is it permitted?

Comment: If they are the same one will/should be eventually deleted, unless by the time it is noticed, both questions have different answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can choose **other (needs ♦ moderator attention)** as the flag and write whatever you want.

Just let us know that it's a duplicate and put the link to the question on the other site in there. That helps a lot :)